How to construct a $3 \times 3$ Matrix $A$ satisfying $X'=AX$ where all solutions $X$ are $2\pi$ periodic?
Good afternoon, I've been asked on a homework problem to do the following:
Give an example of a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ for which all nonequilibrium
solutions of $X^\prime = AX$ are periodic with period $2\pi$.
From studying these types of differential equations, I've found that $3 \times 3$ matrices $A$ with pairs of complex eigenvalues of the form $bi$ for some constant $b$ yield solutions which are periodic in two of the three directions without dealing with the pesky $e^{\lambda_j t}$, but I can't seem to avoid the $e^{\lambda_j t}$ in the real eigenvalue section no matter my construction. I am not certain if this problem allows one to use complex numbers in the construction for $A$, but even in my attempts with that, I fall short in removing the exponential from the solution vector $\overrightarrow{X}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\\x_3(t)\\\end{pmatrix}.$
I would greatly appreciate suggestions about how to construct some $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ with its solution vector $\overrightarrow{X}(t)$ free from exponentials and comprised solely of $\sin(t)$ and/or $\cos(t)$ functions to achieve the $2\pi$ periodicity. Thank you for the help!

How about $A =  i I_3$? Or do you want $A$ to be a real matrix?

Can you do this in the $2\times 2$ case (with a real matrix)? It seems like you understand that. Why not take the remaining eigenvalue to be $0$?
